# Cloudera-manager 4.7

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

Has anyone else had trouble with the new release of Cloudera manager? '4.7' With brand clean ubuntu vm nodes it seems to be placing a file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d called cloudera-manager.list with "http://archive.cloudera.com/cm4/ubuntu/precise/amd64/cm/ precise-cm4.7.0-SNAPSHOT contrib pointed" to as the source, however this url does not exist and when ever it tries to install my nodes if fails.

Does anyone know where this url is kept on the manager so I could change it before it sends it to my nodes?

Comment: So I have found if you just use the 4.6 cloudera manager setup bin from http://archive.cloudera.com/cm4/installer/latest/cloudera-manager-installer.bin it will install correctly and update to 4.7 automatically. That's my work around if anyone else runs into this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Greg,

The repository URL is constructed based on the version of the CM server that you are running. So if the server is reporting itself as "4.7.0-SNAPSHOT", then that's what the node installer will use. Now, we've not published any release that describes itself as 4.7.0-SNAPSHOT, so I'm left scratching my head as to how you got into this situation. If you still have that installation, I would recommend that you:

1) Check the reported version of the server from the Support menu at the top right.

2) Check the full package version(s) as reported by "dpkg -l | grep cloudera"

so that we can establish where the build came from.

Thanks.

PS: The installer url you reference in your update is the latest installer and not a 4.6 installer. It's the one people should use for sure.

Comment: Thanks Philip, you seem to be affiliated with cloudera, think you could help me out with another question I posted about HDFS? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641938/hdfs-using-cloudera-manager-in-private-cloud Thanks!